# Android EditText: Focus Outline

Tags: android, focus, border, android-edittext, outline

In my app, I have a dynamic number of edittexts and after the user changes some settings I need the focus outline graphic to appear on some but not all of the edittexts.  This is needed to highlight the importance of those fields.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I have seen some things about modifying some graphic code   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text)  but I didn't think that was applicable to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The focus outline shows which `EditText` box has focus.  That means it can only be one at a time.  What you can do is put the `EditText` in a `View` that has a stateful drawable for the background.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this.

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to just have that outline on more than one EditText and be able to toggle it on and off.