# Rotating emoji on canvas.drawText

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am rotating and scaling canvas using `canvas.setMatrix()` and then drawing text on canvas using `canvas.drawText();`. That's working as expected but when I try to draw text that contains emojis (android device's default emojis), they don't get rotated. Everything else in the text gets rotated as expected. Also drawing + scaling works as expected for emojis, it's just the rotating that doesn't work.

I really would like to avoid solutions where emoji is drawn on another bitmap and then that bitmap drawn on the canvas with rotation applied.

Text with 0 rotation: https://i.gyazo.com/68ca0a13a1178e1614c976d4f041c8ee.png
Text with rotation applied: https://i.gyazo.com/3f9f9150b89e387e64cb9fc79737ca7d.png

To make clear, the emoji is part of the String element.

```
if(text != null && text.length > 0){
    canvas.save();
    canvas.setMatrix(getDrawingMatrix(rect)); //Get a matrix with scaling, rotation & transformation applied.
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){ //text is a string array containing multiple lines of text.
        String string = text[i];
        if(string.length() > 0){
            canvas.drawText(string, 0, (i)*paint.descent() - (i+1)*paint.ascent(), paint); //each line has different y-value.
        }
    }
    canvas.restore(); //after drawing the matrix is restored to default.
}
```

Ohh, just found out this is actually duplicate of: [emojis not rotating with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366730/emojis-not-rotating-with-canvas)