# How do I add an outline around the text for a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

For my `AppCompatTextView`, I want to add a black outline to the text. Something like the following:
[image: Example text with black outline]

How do I do this in my XML file?

Comment: You've got several options, but you will most probably have to do a custom view. Check out answers for a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text

Comment: @OnurD. The solutions on that post are all showing you how to create a shadow, not an outline.

Comment: Not if you read them carefully. This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65572491/8354184 specifically talks about a "stroke" and this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65572491/8354184 talks about using "shadow" related apis to mimic a "stroke". Give them both a try, I assume one of them should work.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/15225489/12709358