# Android - font (only letters) background color

Tags: android, fonts, colors, background

I want to make in my application some meme - type images. 

I've found some fonts, which I can use, but one thing, which is connecting them is, that when I'm changing textColor property for TextView, which is contining text, I'm changing contour of letters, not whole letter color. When I'm changing background color, I'm changing whole TextView field background (and I want it to be transparent). And the problem is, that in letter I can see background image of photo, which is under the letter, which is problem, because photos can have different colors and text could be not visible. Is there any possibility, to change background color, but only for letters? Or it is a job for someone who is working with graphics and fonts?

There is a photo, which is from my app, which is showing problem.
[image]

And there, what I'm looking for:
[image]
<sub>(source: [canada.com](http://wpmedia.o.canada.com/2014/02/ford_meme_2-e1393613639794.png?w=584))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is text outline or a text shadow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3182393/3249477) has both of those already answered. Or you could instead use solid font types.

Comment: I've changed font, to filled up, set it to white color, and added a black shadow. Maybe it's not, what I was looking for (because shadow is going into transparency), but it's simply and works for now, because is visible on white and black surface. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the text colour not the background colour.

The thing is fonts are all defined like small bitmaps, if you change the colour only the opaque bits will be colourised never the bit's which were left transparent.

I think your only option is to change font