# Draw white Background behind each character in Textview android

Tags: android, textview

I am developing an Android application that needs to have this kind of `TextView` as shown in the image, actually I am trying to add this highlighting effect by using various shadow properties in `TextView` but nothing is working. In my image i need to have white background behind each character.

Here is my `TextView` code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowDx="-0.5"
        android:shadowDy="0.5"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
        android:textColor="#050505"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Here is `TextView` image that i need to make:

[image: Textview]

Comment: Can you tell me which font is this??

Comment: You could [load a custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) that has your desired look. [This site](http://www.fontspace.com/category/bitmap) has some nice ones that I use in games.

Comment: Seems same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text

Comment: i don't have .ttf file of this font and shadow effect is also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like in case of changing font**

```
 textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
```

and other way is you can `downloadAnyFont.ttf` file and put it in asset folder and use like as this

You can download your specified font from     [Free fonts](http://www.fontspace.com/category/bitmap) 
`//Download the requied font`

```
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
    "YourDownloadedfont.ttf");  // Use Download font and paste name at YourDownloadedfont.ttf
textView.setTypeface(type, null);
```

**This may be the real solution for you:**

please view these link for detail 
[MagicTextView](https://github.com/m5/MagicTextView) 
[Customize Android Fonts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601)
[Android textview outline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text)

These will give you idea.
May this solve your problem.