# outline text Android Studio

Tags: android, textview, outline

I've been looking how to outline the a TextView and so far I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text), but is from the 2010. I think that nowadays there is a standard way to outline the text but so far I haven't managed to make it. what I have in my code is the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#3e3e3e"
    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
    />
```

But I get the following rendering error:

> Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported

I would appreciate to know if there is another way to outline the text or how to handle this error! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to run your project with this error? What is the result? Preview doesn't support everything.

Comment: I wrote an answer, check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to Set shadow radius etc. Only setting color cannot make the shadow appear.

Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#3e3e3e"
    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
    android:shadowDx="2"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
/>
```