# How to outline android's TextView text?

Tags: android, user-interface, widget

Is there a way to outline android's TextView text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android textview outline text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is no easy way according to this: [Android textview outline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text)

Comment: The stroke [in the other referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723846/how-do-you-draw-text-with-a-border-on-a-mapview-in-android) in the answer looks simple enough to me, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

So, little late, but [MagicTextView](http://qwerjk.com/magic-text) will do text outlines, amongst other things.

[image]

```
<com.qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
    xmlns:qwerjk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.qwerjk.better_text"
    android:textSize="78dp"
    android:textColor="#ff333333"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    qwerjk:strokeColor="#FFff0000"
    qwerjk:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
    qwerjk:strokeWidth="5"
    android:text="Magic" />
```

Note: I made this, and am posting more for the sake of future travelers than the OP. 
 It's borderline spam, but being on-topic, perhaps acceptable?