# How to make border for text in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want make border for my text in `TextView`. I try find solution for me, but I find only shadow - it's look like:

[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

How can I make border for text?

Comment: try this questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723846/how-do-you-draw-text-with-a-border-on-a-mapview-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text

Comment: @Artem see updated answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class CoustomTextView extends TextView {

    private float strokeWidth;
    private Integer strokeColor;
    private Paint.Join strokeJoin;
    private float strokeMiter;


    public CoustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public CoustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CoustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CoustomTextView);

            if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CoustomTextView_strokeColor)) {
                float strokeWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CoustomTextView_strokeWidth, 1);
                int strokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CoustomTextView_strokeColor, 0xff000000);
                float strokeMiter = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CoustomTextView_strokeMiter, 10);
                Paint.Join strokeJoin = null;
                switch (a.getInt(R.styleable.CoustomTextView_strokeJoinStyle, 0)) {
                    case (0):
                        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.MITER;
                        break;
                    case (1):
                        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.BEVEL;
                        break;
                    case (2):
                        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND;
                        break;
                }
                this.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor, strokeJoin, strokeMiter);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setStroke(float width, int color, Paint.Join join, float miter) {
        strokeWidth = width;
        strokeColor = color;
        strokeJoin = join;
        strokeMiter = miter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int restoreColor = this.getCurrentTextColor();
        if (strokeColor != null) {
            TextPaint paint = this.getPaint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(strokeJoin);
            paint.setStrokeMiter(strokeMiter);
            this.setTextColor(strokeColor);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            this.setTextColor(restoreColor);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CoustomTextView coustomTextView = (CoustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.pager_title);
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">


    <pk.sohail.gallerytest.activity.CoustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/pager_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt_title_photo_gallery"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:outerShadowRadius="10dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/title_text_color"
        app:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**attars:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CoustomTextView">

        <attr name="outerShadowRadius" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="strokeWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="strokeMiter" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="strokeColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="strokeJoinStyle">
            <enum name="miter" value="0" />
            <enum name="bevel" value="1" />
            <enum name="round" value="2" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**Programmatically:**

```
CoustomTextView mtxt_name = (CoustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.pager_title);
```

Use `setStroke();` method before calling `setText();`

Comment: This solution will cause infinite number of invalidates, because setTextColor calls invalidate if color changed.