# custom text style with two color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors, background-color

I want know it's possible to style text like this:

[image: Text style example]

Note : I am using `shadow` but it doesn't seem useful to me. I would like to get a two color text like in the picture above.

This is my code:

```
<com.example.fabulous.comic.CustomTXT
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:shadowColor="@color/blacke"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:text="hellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: apply a custom font to your text

Comment: *Quick fix* : Use a custom TypeFace that looks like that.

Comment: @erfan check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create text like this see my [**previous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397267/how-to-make-border-for-text-in-textview/38397419#38397419) detail answer here.

Set text color to `white` and outline color to`black.`

Comment: why create another view when you can use fonts?

Comment: yes you can use fonts but you cant control their properties like outline width, color same as inside color.

Comment: @erfan  show some more love by tick mark and vote up in both posts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you chose a custom font with a custom color?
This [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601) might help you to customize your font .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 <TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:shadowColor="@color/black" 
android:shadowRadius="2"/>
```

> **you increase the radius as you want and color as you wish**

[image]

> You Can Also Trying using the Font.....

**Used Montserrat.ttp download for google and also you used more fonts.. as you wish**

```
    String fontPath = "fonts/mont.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    btn_reload.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using shadows in TextView should do the trick to get an outline effect :

```
android:shadowColor="#000000"
android:shadowDx="1.5"
android:shadowDy="1.3"
android:shadowRadius="1.6"
android:text="CCC"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

You can also use a web service like [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com) to find the police used in any picture. I used your picture to find the closest match and got this answer:

[image: WhatTheFont answer]

The police is **Minutia Outline** and you can [find it here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/elemeno/minutia/outline/).

I am not sure this is the solution you were after, but using this police will get you exactly what you have in your picture.

If you prefer to not use fonts, you could simply use some CSS to style your text, [webView to use html/css](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in Android like so:

```css
.strokeme
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
    font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<div class="strokeme">
    Is this what you were looking for?
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer was helpful, please upvote it. Thank you.