# TextView Outline in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to implement `TextView` outline in one of my android application which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397419/9017779)

I have made custom textView class as mentioned and there no any error. I am trying to use it in my activity but as I am learning yet, I am confused to use it in `Activity` as `setStroke` method.

I am trying as below

```
text_quotes.setStroke(0,R.color.toolbar_color,0,0);
```

can anybody please suggest me this four filed which value I should enter?

in `CustomeTextView` class is defined as below

```
strokeWidth = width;
strokeColor = color;
strokeJoin = join;
strokeMiter = miter;
```

I have issue in **strokeJoin** field, which value I should enter for it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StrokeJoin seems to be a value of the Paint.Join enumeration.
So you should try one of the Paint.Join values like :

```
Paint.Join.MITER;
Paint.Join.BEVEL;
Paint.Join.ROUND;
```

Look the different values here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Join.html