# Add opaque "shadow" (outline) to Android TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, drawing, mapsforge

I have a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) in my [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to which I want to add a shadow. It is supposed to look like in [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) (100% opaque):

[image: what I want]

But it looks like this:

[image: What I have]

You can see that the current shadow is blurred and fades away. I want a solid, opaque shadow. But how?

My current code is:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/speedTextView"
    android:text="25 km/h"

    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="6"
/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text

Comment: Non of the solutions provided there did work for me until now. I keep trying ...

Comment: The solution you want is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23909516/4504191 You set a paint style of STROKE then set the stroke width.  The white outline in your image is the stroke.

Comment: I have a MapsForge activity with its own Paint methods. I did not get it to work there.

Answer (score 16):

I tried all the hacks, tips and tricks in the other posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723846/how-do-you-draw-text-with-a-border-on-a-mapview-in-android).

None of them works that great or looks so good.

#### Now this is how you really do it (found in the Source of the [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) app):

You use a FrameLayout (which has the characteristic of laying its components over each other) and put 2 TextViews inside at the same position.

MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#445566">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewShadowId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:text="123 ABC" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:text="123 ABC"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the `onCreate` method of your activity you set the stroke width of the shadow TextView and change it from FILL to STROKE:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        //here comes the magic
        TextView textViewShadow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewShadowId);
        textViewShadow.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5);
        textViewShadow.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: two textviews, so bad solution

Comment: @user924 I don't really think it's bad just because it has two more views. This is the most reliable and simplest solution out there.

Comment: this is actually a feasible solution.. but the thing is it will be difficult to customize this... like using different textview attributes for differentl layout

Comment: This is very simple solution if you don't want to implement it in only one place. I encountered the problem of clipping the outline. I resolved it by adding spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue, with calling `setTextColor` in `onDraw` causing infinite draw loop. I wanted to make my custom text view have a different fill color than the outline color when it rendered text. Which is why I was calling `setTextColor` multiple times in `onDraw`.

I found an alternative solution using an `OutlineSpan` see https://github.com/santaevpavel/OutlineSpan. This is better than making the layout hierarchy complicated with multiple TextViews or using reflection and requires minimal changes. See the github page for more details.
Example

```
val outlineSpan = OutlineSpan(
    strokeColor = Color.RED,
    strokeWidth = 4F
)
val text = "Outlined text"
val spannable = SpannableString(text)
spannable.setSpan(outlineSpan, 0, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

// Set text of TextView
binding.outlinedText.text = spannable
```