# How to add a border to the characters on a TextView

Tags: android

I understand I can add a shadow to it that will look like a border, with:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowRadius="10" />
```

But that shadow has a certain amount of blur to make it look shadowy that I don't know how to remove. How can I add a border to my characters, just like that shadow, in a way that it doesn't look like a shadow, but like a border?

Example:

[image: like this]

Comment: Add a background to your textView.
like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview

Comment: no, I don't want the border around my textView, I want it around my characters like this: http://www.gimpology.com/uploads/3_8_8.png

Comment: the user YGHM write the answer you need in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text

Comment: All of the answers in the above-mentioned post will put your `TextView` into an endless draw loop, 'cause they're calling methods in `onDraw()` that invalidate the `View`. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106454/add-opaque-shadow-outline-to-android-textview) for some better options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add opaque "shadow" (outline) to Android TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106454/add-opaque-shadow-outline-to-android-textview)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106454/add-opaque-shadow-outline-to-android-textview) solved my problem, thanks