# Android border around each letter on a textview

Tags: android, xml, text, kotlin, textview

I would like to add a border independently around each letter of my `Textview` like this example :

[image]

Actually I have a basic `TextView` in purple , but I would like to add yellow border as you can see on this image.

Here is my actual `XML` of my `Textview` which is the same as the picture but WITHOUT yellow border around letters :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Coins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserratbold"
    android:textColor="#a51ebf"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/box"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/box"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.55"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/box"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />
```

I tried many solutions but nothing work especially , let me know if you have something. Thanks !

Comment: If the text is not mutable i.e. if it doesn't change try using an ImageView with the said image. If not you need to write a custom textview where you can divide one textview into individual textviews and apply background to them

Comment: Try this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106454/add-opaque-shadow-outline-to-android-textview

Comment: @HawkPriest Unfortunately , this text is mutable , it changes everytime.

Comment: @Manu13k Are you trying to achieve the stroke property of a text?

Comment: @ImMathan Yes but in a different color , like I said I would like a yellow stroke behid my purple text

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" it by adding another Textview at the same position in yellow color and with stroke like this :

```
TextView textViewShadow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewShadowId);
    textViewShadow.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5);
    textViewShadow.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

What do you think ? It is bad for the application ?

EDIT :  I Created a custom Textview , now it works you can see the answer here : [Android textview outline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: No seems not a best practice. You extend a Custom Textview and apply `stroke` and `fill` color on the same canvas.

Comment: That will be applied on each element or only the entire word ? @ImMathan

Comment: You can apply to each letter.