# Unable to increase border width of characters on textview

Tags: java, android

I am trying my best increasing border width of characters on textview but i haven't founded anything like following.
As you can see, outlined borders are black in order to constrast with backgrounds.
So, how can i do something like that? I mean, i would like to do this with .xml or .java

**Outlined black**

[image]

Comment: try to add shadow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486936/android-shadow-on-text

Comment: thanks but this is not drawing black outline, this is adding shadow

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723846/how-do-you-draw-text-with-a-border-on-a-mapview-in-android#answer-2151964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download](https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/outline-fonts.htm) the font type and add it to the items you need

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6XNU.png]

Select File / New Folder / Assets Folder

Right click on **assets** and create a folder called **fonts**

Put your font file in **assets** **>** **fonts**

Use this

```
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
    myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: I have been trying this too and i think is the best option, but i am still wondering which is the correct way to do this programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can set shadow for your textview using attributes below.

```
android:shadowColor="@color/black"
android:shadowDx="1"
android:shadowDy="1"
android:shadowRadius="2"
```

For more information [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373264/1512199)